# How to manipulate Firefox UI with Addon SDK?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

It is easy to manipulate page content via the Firefox Addon SDK.

But how can I access UI elements, respectively their CSS properties, via the SDK, like I can  in the [userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css&printable=yes)?

More precisely: I want to change the background of (inactive) tabs according to their current URL.

What are the keywords to look for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get the browser window. So this code gets the most recent browser window:

```
const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow } = require('sdk/window/utils');
var aDOMWindow = getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
if (aDOMWindow.gBrowser && aDOMWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer) {
var tabs = aDOMWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes;
for (var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) {
tabs[i].style.fontWeight = 'bold';
}
}
```

this sets the font to bold in all tabs

Comment: Excellent! The API structure kind of confuses me sometimes.

Comment: Cool man. To get all the browser windows use `Services.wm.getEnumerator('navigator:browser')` im not sure what the equivalent is for Add-on SDK. [Enumerating Windows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWindowMediator?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=nsIWindowMediator#Enumerating_windows)